# In iOS, how do I get keyboard information to prevent keyboard overlay of text fields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, notifications, uitextfielddelegate

I am setting up a **NOTIFICATION** to get **KEYBOARD** information to adjust the view so that the selected text field is not covered by the **KEYBOARD**.

```
@property CGSize keyboard;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:@"UIKeyboardWillShowNotification"
                                               object:nil];
    ...
}

- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
    self.keyboard = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
}
```

I have set up the **UITextFieldDelegate** so I can use the **KEYBOARD** information in

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Everything works perfectly ...

except for the very first time.

The **NOTIFICATION** that sets up the **KEYBOARD** property is called after **textFieldDidBeginEditing** so the very first time the **KEYBOARD** property has not been set up so it displays incorrectly.

After that things are fine since the **KEYBOARD** property has already been set up and the values don't change.

How can I get the **KEYBOARD** information before the first execution of **textFieldDidBeginEditing**?

**EDIT**:

Did find something of a solution, and it does seem to work, but it feels a little hackish to me and I'm still wondering if there is a way to get the keyboard information.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.txtField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.txtField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Does give a brief flash at the very bottom of the screen as it displays and hides the keyboard, which I don't like, but it's probably not very obvious or noticeable to someone that doesn't know to look for it.

I have to break up the **becomeFirstResponder** and **resignFirstResponder** into different methods because if they get called from the same method then **keyboardWillShow** does not get called.

Also, can not place **becomeFirstResponder** in **viewDidLoad** because **keyboardWillShow** is not called in that situation either.

If anyone has an improvement, or a better way, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is that instead of setting the text field's frame in the begin editing, you can iterate through your text fields checking the `isFirstResponder`property, and move the frame of the one that is first responder. You can do all that in your method where you get the keyboards frame.